# Ошибка в Exсel, неправильно срабатывает логика

Tags: excel

В Exсel не срабатывает 'значение если истина'
![1]https://ibb.co/eboqkU
![2]https://ibb.co/mJzKep

```
=ЕСЛИ(РАЗНДАТ(E2;$J$2;"d")=0;"работает";ЕСЛИ(РАЗНДАТ(G2;$J$2;"d")>30;"не
работает";ЕСЛИ((И((ТЕКСТ(G2-E2;"ч"))*1>=0;(ТЕКСТ(G2-E2;"ч"))*1<6));"скорее 
работает";"требует выяснения")))
```

в чем причина ?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Напишите хоть формулу. У меня ф-ция ЕСЛИ работает точно хорошо. Возможно в процессе вычислений возникает "исключение" `#ОШИБКА`. Но всётаки непонятно в чём проблема у вас с excel.

Comment: @nick_n_a добавил

Comment: Скорее всего у вас нет истины. Разбейте вашу формулу на несколько цепных что б было видно промежуточный результат, распутайте клубок самостоятельно - и вы увидите какая из формул дала не то.

Answer (score 0):

ошибка была в том, что в привидении типов стояла буква ч, а везде английские d-day. h-hour

Comment: Не срабатывает логика, т.е. не срабатывает ЕСЛИ? И... что, разве неправильно работает?  d-day к функции `ЕСЛИ` ну не относится. Дописать - правильно, это привело к тому что появился `FALSE` или `#ERROR` или пустая строка, и как итог - функция `ЕСЛИ` c аргументами `FALSE` или `#ERROR` дала результат, но не такой как ожидалось. Тогда ответ будет логически завершённым.

Comment: `(И((ТЕКСТ(G2-E2;"ч"))*1>=0;(ТЕКСТ(G2-E2;"ч"))*1<6))` - много лишнего. достаточно `ЧАС(G2-E2)<6`